# s3cmd error on sync: S3 error: 400 (InvalidRequest)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I'm trying to configure s3cmd to backup some directories on my server to my AWS S3 bucket. My problem is that when I do the sync command:  `s3cmd sync -r -p --no-delete-removed /path/to/dir s3://bucketname/dir/`
I get the following error:

```
ERROR: S3 error: 400 (InvalidRequest): The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
```

I am using s3cmd version 1.5.0-rc1. On my other server I am using the same version of s3cmd and use the same command and everything is working fine.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my fault. Updated the version to s3cmd 1.6.1 and everything is working fine now!

You can download the latest version at https://sourceforge.net/projects/s3tools/files/s3cmd/